# UIViewController loading a UINavigationController modally from a viewController and a back button

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show back button on the RootViewController of the UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283218/how-to-show-back-button-on-the-rootviewcontroller-of-the-uinavigationcontroller)

I'm currently working on an app using storyboards (supporting IOS 5.1-6).  My rootViewController is a `UIViewController`.  When displaying new content I'm loading different UIViewControllers modally using segue's.  On one particular view I want to load a `UINavigationController` with a ToolBar at the bottom so I can go back to my `UIViewController` by tapping the back button.

I'm a bit confused because on the NavigationController I cannot dismiss the current `NavigationController` because of no back button.  If I add a back button I won't see it because the `NavigationController` is on the top of the stack?

Can someone point my in the right direction or provide some insight here on how to dismiss this NavigationController since it was called modally?

As always, thanks in advance for the help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `UIBarButtonItem` to the `UINavigationController`.  Because you're presenting the new view modally, it should be a "Done/Dismiss" button (dismisses the modal VC) rather than a "Back" button (pops the view back).

When you present the modal view controller initially, you can pass a dismiss block which will be called when you press the dismiss button that dismisses the view controller.

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

The key distinction here is the back button vs the dismiss button concept.  This is explained in Apple's HIG documentation.

[UIViewController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)